# Button to add single line break in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am developing a plugin to show a "Next Line" button on the CKEditor toolbar.  But when I start typing and press the next line button  its not working on a single click ie I has to click twice to go to the next line.

I am using CKEditor 4.

What should I do extra to go to the next line on a single click. Can any one help me out of this?

This is my `plugin.js` code

```
 CKEDITOR.plugins.add('newline',
{
    init: function (editor) {

        var pluginName = 'newline';

        editor.ui.addButton('newline',

            {
                label: 'New Line',
                command: 'NewLine',
                icon: CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('newline') + 'images/new_line.png'
            });

       var cmd = editor.addCommand('NewLine', { exec: showNewLine });

    }

});

function showNewLine(e) {

   e.insertHtml('<br />');

   // Here if I replace the above line with  e.insertHtml('<br />&nbsp;'); it will work fine but is adding an extra space at the beggining of each line.

}
```

All I need is a button(when clicked) that works exactly like Shift+Enter in the ckeditor.

Comment: Please can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button should execute `shiftEnter` command. It's much more complicated than just inserting `<br />`.

```
editor.execCommand( 'shiftEnter' );
```

Comment: Thanks, its just perfect now.